# How to add the elements from one list to another list in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two lists:

```
list_1 = [100,100,50,40,40,20,10]
list_2 = [5,25,50,120]
```

I want to move the numbers/elements from list_2 to list_1 in the descending order in a nested list:

```
[[100,100,50,40,40,20,10,5],[100,100,50,40,40,25,20,10],[100,100,50,50,40,40,20,10],[120,100,100,50,40,40,20,10]]
```

How to achieve this using Python 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the code below:

```
list_1 = [100, 100, 50, 40, 40, 20, 10]
list_2 = [5, 25, 50, 120]

final_list = []

for l1 in list_2:
    temp_list_1 = list_1.copy()
    temp_list_1.append(l1)        
    temp_list_1.sort(reverse=True)

    final_list.append(temp_list_1)

print(final_list)
```

Explanation:

Loop over the elements of *list_2* and append it on the *temp_list_1*. Then sort it in descending order. Finally append the sorted list on a new *final_list*.

Answer (score 1):

```
list_1 = [100,100,50,40,40,20,10]
list_2 = [5,25,50,120]

lst = [sorted(list_1 + [list_2[i]], reverse=True) for i in range(len(list_2))]

print(lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try list comprehension here :

```
main_list = [sorted(list_1+[i], reverse=True) for i in list_2]
print(main_list)
```

Here I'm adding each element to list_1 and sort it in descending order then to main list.

The O/P will be like :

```
[[100, 100, 50, 40, 40, 20, 10, 5], [100, 100, 50, 40, 40, 25, 20, 10], 
[100, 100, 50, 50, 40, 40, 20, 10], [120, 100, 100, 50, 40, 40, 20, 10]]
```